# Help with set up of calculus problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've had the idea of this question for a while, I think I have the proper knowledge to solve it but I would like some help to set it up.

"Calculate the rate that the distance of the horizon from eye level changes as eye level increases or decreases"

Comment: It would help to know a relation between eye level and distance of the horizon from eye level. Do you know how to find that?

Comment: At 0 height it's infinity. Maybe we can use some type of right triangle rules but I'm not too sure

Comment: Let $R$ be the radius of Earth and $h$ the height of your eye over the surface. The distance from horizon is the second side of a right triangle whose other side has lenght $R$ and the hypotenuse is $R+h$ long.